# Is it possible to miss events when opening a WebSocket?

Tags: go, websocket, webassembly

I am looking at the properties on WebSocket.  Specifically I want to handle connection errors, but I am a little perturbed by the fact that I can only set the listener property after the connection establishment has been started.  Is there any risk here that I might miss for example an `onerror` message triggered by the connection attempt?  eg no network interface

Looking at the spec. it sounds like the connection attempt will happen in parallel/asynch, and I know that will anyway be pretty slow in comparison to executing a couple extra lines of code, even though my connection is LAN based.  My concern is that I am calling the js functions from WASM compiled down from Go.  And I know there is some performance overhead in these calls across the language boundaries.  Should I be concerned?

example code from MDN:

```
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});
```

[example source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Examples)

what I am doing:

```
    webSocketCon := js.Global().Get("WebSocket")
    ws := webSocketCon.New(url)
    handlerError := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        //code to handle error
        return nil
    })
    ws.Set("onerror", handlerError)
```

Comment: JavaScript is a single threaded language, so if you put the two lines after each other in the same function call it's impossible to miss the `onopen` event since the asynchrounous task of establishing the connection is not run until you current execution scope has ended.

Comment: Interesting, so do you think that will also hold true for calls between WASM and JavaScript?

Comment: No. You need to create the websocket and attach the `onopen` event listener in the same function call from wasm.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense, would you like to add that as the answer. thanks.